# Highlight current page menu link in Tumblr

Tags: javascript, css, tumblr

It seems so obvious, but eventually Tumblr does not provide any official solution for this scenario.. Could this be done only using JQuery, going through dom elements and matching a hrefs against web url and then injecting custom css attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Found javascript solution in this page:[link](http://www.itworld.com/development/351097/setting-active-menu-item-based-current-url-jquery)